# Set default values in Imputer object using different dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, sklearn-pandas

Can we fit a different data set (let`s say Y) to calculate a mean value and transform it to the X data sets? Can we provide a default value when a NULL value occurs in a data set using Imputer object.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean',axis=0)

#Y data set in fit imputer
imputer = imputer.fit(Y[:, 1:3])

#Here I want to set the mean value created from Y data set and transform it 
#to the X. How can we handle this scenario.

X[:, 1:3]=imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

Instead of using fit, can we set any predefined default values?

Comment: You want to replace `NaN` values of `X` with a pre-chosen value?

Comment: About your first question: "Can we fit a different data set (let`s say Y) to calculate a mean value and transform it to the X data sets?" - the anwer is yes.

Comment: Yes, I want to use default values to the data sets which I hold. Thanks @Jundiaius